# Navigation right bar button image is white from url

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I'm attempting to show an image from a url in the right bar button of the navigation bar. All I'm seeing is a white image. The image loads fine in other parts of the app with the same technique. What am I doing wrong?

```
[[SDWebImageDownloader sharedDownloader]downloadImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.avatarUrl] options:SDWebImageDownloaderContinueInBackground progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {

} completed:^(UIImage *image, NSData *data, NSError *error, BOOL finished) {

  UIBarButtonItem *avatarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[Utils imageWithImage:image scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(32.0f, 32.0f)] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(showUser)];
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = avatarItem;

}];
```

Comment: Only the alpha channel is used in a bar button.

Comment: Thats the problem , you should post it as an answer. :-)

Comment: What do I need to do to solve the issue?

Comment: I tried to stick the image on a button before adding it but it doesn't even show then.